# Cant use with clauses in find_by_sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Activerecord seems to be peeking at my sql and getting it wrong.  I am finding that this:

```
sql = "
  select etn.* 
  from edittree_name etn where id = #{id}"  
Name.find_by_sql(sql)
```

works, but this:

```
sql = "
  with pp as ( select * from dual)
  select etn.* 
  from edittree_name etn where id = #{id}"  
Name.find_by_sql(sql)
```

Gives me a "undefined method `each' for 1:Fixnum".

Any clues? Is there a "find_by_raw_sql (and don't try to understand it yourself)" method?

Answer (score -1):

Ok. Problem solved.

Something in RoR does *not* like those oracle "with" clauses, and the problem seems to be that RoR expects to see a "select" clause first thing. 
You can address this by shifting the with clause into the from clause.

This

```
with xx(parent) as (
  select parent from link where
    link.child = {#id}
  union all
  select parent from xx, link 
    where link.child = xx.parent
)
select foo.*
from foo,xx 
where foo.id = xx.parent
```

becomes this

```
select foo.*
from foo, 
(
  with xx(parent) as (
    select parent from link 
      where link.child = {#id}
    union all
    select parent from xx, link 
      where link.child = xx.parent
  )
  select * from xx
) yy
where foo.id = yy.parent
```

The issue seems to be that rails needs to parse the new sql syntax correctly